# Change value of a scroll bar without triggering the change-listener

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to VBA and appreciate your help!

- I have a PowerPoint with just one slide.
  Several scroll bars on that slide. The user can change values with them.
  Then, `scrollbarName_change()` will be executed.
- But sometimes my codes changes that scroll bar and I don't want the code of the `scrollbarName_change()` listener be executed.
- I thought about a global variable which I have to set "true" every time my code and not the user tries to change the scroll bar value. Scroll bar change would check if the variable is true/false before executing the code, but that's really nasty, I think. Also, I am not sure if there couldn't be time conflicts with other times I try to change the variable.

Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing nasty about your idea! I did use a CheckBox instead of a global variable:

```
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54380340/vba-ppt-change-value-of-a-scroll-bar-without-triggerin-the-change-listener
'(VBA-PPT) Change value of a scroll bar without triggerin the change-listener

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
'    MsgBox "Click"
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    If Not (CheckBox1) Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "SB1"
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBar2_Change()
    If Not (CheckBox1) Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "SB2"
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBar3_Change()
    If Not (CheckBox1) Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "SB3"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like i cant upvote your commend, i am sorry :(

Comment: I upvoted it for you @MarcSchuster. Maintaining a global for this kind of thing isn't really a big problem and can be very helpful in a complex form where changes to one control might trigger changes to another control. In cases like that, I'll set a boolean Updating to true at the start of the routine, then set it back to False later. Then in each of the event handlers for individual controls, I'll start with If Not Updating Then {handle the event] End If